# I changed the username by changing /etc/passwd

Tags: passwd

I did something REALLY silly - I did ...
sudo vi /etc/passwd
Then I changed the username to the user I wanted, I exited the file.

Now - the user password no longer matches, I can't change the password as I can't enter the current password. I can't sudo (as the password no longer matches). I'm still logged in though.

Is there a way out? I encrypted the disk - if I take it out, can I mount it on another machine?

Sam

Comment: If that last one works you can do that from a live session. And a live session is likely to work better and easier than taking it out. Have a look if that works 1st and then report back ;)

Comment: If you still have a local session open, sometimes `pkexec` works in situations where `sudo` doesn't - try `pkexec vipw` (or `pkexec vipw -s` if you wish to change the shadow file to be consistent with the modified passwd file).

Comment: I have the same issue, the problem is that it asks for root user password wich i dont know.@steeldriver

Answer (score 1):

I just did the following and solved my issue:

```
su - newusername /* will prompt for password */
```

I entered the old password and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the username in /etc/shadow too.  Then the name/password will match and should work.  Check the /etc/group and /etc/gshadow files too for the  old username, and change if necessary.  Then check the /etc/sudoers file,... etc.
  Probably, you should just have added a new user (useradd), added the new user to sudoers, and when things work, delete the old user.

Comment: does not work, the system asks me for the password of the new user which is lost.